How to Fix: Unable to locate element: after the first run using xpath on chrome
I'm trying to automate a (<select> tag) selection of the origin and destiny from this web page (https://www.boa.bo/BoAWebsite) just to select the city from departure.
The first run, all ok, but if I'm trying to run more times I have the error

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='select_desde']"})

Currently I'm learning selenium with Java so I would appreciate some strategies on the solution of this kind of problems in the future.
I tried to use below code:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='select_desde']")); 

adding a driver wait and also changing the web element on By.ID or By.cssSelector.
First time running the code works fine, but after that only the mentioned error. Below is the reference code:
public class Dropdwn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\ChromeDriverSelenium\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");  //Specify the location in machine where the driver is located
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //opening the web page
        driver.get("https://www.boa.bo/BoAWebsite");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))

        WebElement elementoD = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='select_desde']"));
        //Using cssSelector
        //WebElement elementoD = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#select_desde"));
        Select selectorD = new Select(elementoD);

        selectorD.selectByValue("CBB");        
    }
}


I think you should try to add
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20)); the time for finding element

You have created a WebDriverWait object, but never used it.
Change below line:
WebElement elementoD = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='select_desde']"));

TO:
WebElement elementoD = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@id='select_desde']")));

Imports you will need:
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;


Do you know where can i read any documentation on why is needed to use the ExpectedCondition.elementToClickable function on this kind of cases?

Here is the official Link on waiting strategies documentation. If this answer has helped you resolve the issue, you should accept the answer so that it is not left un-answered. What should I do when someone answers my question?
